# How can I use Spring Security along with a Spring Boot Rest API?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, spring-security

I made a webapp which manages employees. I want to split it to two, for the admin and user, and further disable some of the functions in the users interface based on their role. From what I read, Spring Security is ideal for it, but my problem is my interface is one project while the API is a seperate project, so I dont have any daos etc in the project with the jsp files. (I use AJAX to get the neccessary info from the database)

How can I use Spring Security in such a scenario and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: So is your backend a Springboot server currently ? How do you ascertain in backend that client is user/admin, do you use some authn/authz mechanism like tokens or passwords? Or are all expected clients pre-loaded in the database so that backend can query this? based on this we can have the backend make the decision of authenticating the user and UI can determine the next operation.

Comment: @srinivaskumar So still pretty new to this, so I did all the authentication using javascript (very bad practice ik, but i didnt know another way) The user role is in the database as well. I have an AJAX call to validate whether the username and password matches, and from there I call another AJAX using the users username (which is also his/her id) to get all the information about that user. From there I redirect them to the admin/user page depending on their role. I was hoping to do this part using another method instead of using JS

Answer (score 0):

Currently your frontend(User Interface of webapp) is directly interacting with the database, doing the AuthN/AuthZ by itself. So, in order to decouple UI from the auth you can introduce a backend(i.e springboot) which will in-turn take care of transactions with the database. Considering the use-case where a simple user-password is used, there is no need for spring security as the simple decision logic can be taken in your code itself.

- Database: You can use the in memory database of springboot [JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) or you can stick with your current database, just make sure it has APIs through which your server can interact with it.
- Backend(Springboot): So this can have couple of REST API endpoints which can be used by UI to query about user.

```
@RestController
public class CustomRestController() {
  
    //Can be a post method, get is an exmaple.
    @GetMapping("/authorize")
    public boolean authorize(...) {
       //Queries database and returns boolean based on match/unmatch.
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/details")
    public UserDetails getUserDetailsForUserId(...) {
      //UserDetails is a custom user object which you populate by querying 
        database.
      //you can choose which details to send/not to send based on type of user.
    }
}
```

- FrontEnd(Ajax): Makes calls to backend rest api endpoint.
  First, it calls `/authorize` to ensure client is authenticated to login.
  Upon success it calls `/user/details`. Now some data is retrieved only for
  admin based on backend filtering. Since some data is absent those need be
  showed at all(in case of normal user)

References:

1. [Spring Restful services](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)
2. [Another Tutorial on rest and spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)